# Is it possible to locally replace a website's Javascript when the page loads?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web

I am not talking about using an add-on such as greasemonkey to inject new javascript. I'm talking about providing (possibly a browser extension of some sort) a custom js script to be loaded *instead* of the one that the page provides.

Example:
Page has `<script src="script.js"></script>`

I would like to tell my browser to run X code *instead* of what was in script.js

Thank you. Sorry if the question is not very clear.

Comment: Look at Fiddler (on Windows) or Charles (on Mac) - they are local proxys  that allow you to manipulate requests/responses, so you can map  a new response (i.e. your custom javascript file) to a request for a file.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways to programmatically execute Javascript on a web page.

### Add Another Script Tag

If you can save your script on the web somewhere, then you can just insert a new script tag referencing it.

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.setAttribute('src', 'http://yourscript.com/script.js');
document.body.appendChild(script);
```

Alternatively, if you can find the existing script tag, you can just change the source.

```
var script = document.getElementById('my-script');
script.setAttribute('src', 'http://yourscript.com/script.js');
```

### Eval the Code

If you already have the code you want to execute, then you can write a script that uses Javascript's `eval` function to run it.

```
var code = '...';
eval(code);
```

**Warning!** Unless you absolutely trust the source of the code, then using eval can be dangerous.

Answer (score 0):

Open the developer tools in chrome (F12 on windows), navigate to your .js source file, then proceed to promptly modify what you see in the editor that is presented. Chrome only persists these changes as long as the page doesnt get refreshed. Once the page is refreshed it drags files from the server again and your local changes will be lost.

You can do a replace of the code in that file.

Hope this was what you were looking for!

Answer (score 0):

Try this, this will inject a script element into the page. I am finding the way to remove the existing element.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.write("<script src='codex.js'></script>");
</script>
```